apk not found/ apk doesn't exist - System App on Anbox Cloud Appliance
I'm trying to install an app as system app in anbox cloud appliance however it keeps giving me this error: "APK not found..." or it says "APK doesn't exist" with the given address. even though I tried every type of addressing whether correct or even incorrect ones.
I installed system app couple of times and when I named pre-start.sh hook file it worked, but now it keeps me giving me this error. The strange thing is previous times, for each system app, different type of addressing was used and it worked; but the common thing they had was the name of pre-start file which was: pre-start.sh.
The suggested addressing from the documentation was --apk="${ADDON_DIR}/app.apk which I tried and I also edited in many ways but it doesn't work.
This is the directory structure:
├── app.apk
├── hooks
│   └── pre-start
└── manifest.yaml

These are the commands in pre-start file:
if  [ "$INSTANCE_TYPE" = "regular" ]; then
  
exit 0

fi

aam install-system-app \
  --package-name=com.canonical.anbox.out_of_band_v2 \
  --apk=/home/faraz/mine/app.apk

For my last attempts, I renamed the pre-start to pre-start.sh and tried different ways of addressing the APK, however right now it doesn't work.
keep in mind that i get the error for the application not created in the dashboard of anbox cloud appliance, and it has a log section which i see the error messages from there; the error is this:

Jul 26 10:25:13 ams-cqhnisc921260635dot0 anbox-starter[1142]: ERROR: apk file /home/faraz/mine/app.apk doesn't exist
even though the apk exists in the mine directory with all of the permissions granted.


Post the command you entered, and the full error message. Also describe what exactly you did between the time when it worked, and now where it does not work.

i added more details to the question in case someone needs it

I don't see the complete error message you get from the aam command. Also, it would be helpful to know whether the aam  command works if you run it manually from the shell.

I've edited the question a bit, so that the error message is easier to read. The question looks clear now (and I retracted my closing vote). I would remove the bash tag, because I don't think it is a bash problem. The android specialists need to have a look at it. I can't even judge, whether it is programming related, or just a configuration problem (in which case you should ask the question to be moved to [su]).

i added the error message and complete case, thank you @user1934428
also when you run the script in the terminal. it doesn't recognize the 'aam' command since the aam command belongs to the "anbox cloud appliance"; at least that's what i think.

From my (limited) knowledge, I think it does recognize the aam, otherwise you would get an error message saying bash: aam: command not found. That's the reason why I think it is a problem related to the way you are using the android development tools.

as a matter of fact, when i run the script in the terminal it says: aam: command not found. so inspite of that your opinion is that problem is with the android tools?

If aam is not found, you need to fix your PATH (as with every command which is not found). This is unrelated, because when you get the error message which you have posted, the PATH is obviously fine. BTW, just for the safe side: You did check that the file /home/faraz/mine/app.apk exists, did you?

yes the apk actually exists and i'm still trying different ways of addressing the path and still haven't got the result i desired.
